# Codeigniter session Not Working across all controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller, global

what would be the best way to allow sessions to be used across all my controllers? i think there are a couple ways to do it:

1) define() session into global variables. I heard this is not best approach
2) set up a general MY_controller and extend every other controller to it. set up sessions there and that will make them available in all classes
3) something that has to do with adding &get_instance() to the __constructor() function that comes on the top of every controller
what would be the best way of setting sessions across all controllers?

i wasnt able to use any of these methods. any ideas would be helpful. Thanks

**BTW, the problem was that codeigniter doesn't like simultaneous ajax requests. They interfere with each other and session data gets erased.**

Comment: a `$_SESSION` is a super global, its available within all your controllers. Can you explain what you mean by session if not $_SESSION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to set some config variables in `application/config/config.php` File

`$config['cookie_domain']` and `$config['cookie_path']` seems to be causing this problem. If so then just unset their value to "" and give it a try.

Comment: Anybody who is going to try this solution i want to inform in my case 'cookie_domain' is '' and and cookie_path ='/' and still its giving error and if i put cookie_path to '' error is still there

Answer (score 5):

Once you set a session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name', 'value');
```

You can call it **anywhere**:

```
$this->session->userdata('name');
```

However, for session to work you need to initialize the Session class first manually! This can be done by calling this function:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Or you can let CodeIgniter to [auto-load](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) it:

***application/config/autoload.php***

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

It's a best practice to set a session in the controller.

I don't see any complications in here.

Comment: thing is, codeigniter doesnt use sessions, so there is no global array where i can access them. once i move to a different controller i lose them

Comment: "once i move to a different controller i lose them" - Are you sure? Elaborate more, I've been using CodeIgniter for a while and I don't encounter what you just said.

Comment: ok, so i do set_userdata() and i can echo it in the `controller` from which i called the `model` that did set_userdata(). but when i try to echo these variables in another controller they are just not there. 
  has that happened to you?

Comment: I just want to reconfirm this thing does occur

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `$config['cookie_secure']` to `FALSE` when in development mode

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is having trouble with codeigniter sessions, dont bother. 
They are done through cookies, and those have a lot of bugs if you have lots of ajax on your website. switch to native sessions.